# App Engine cron jobs don't show in log

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

We have a cron job scheduled to a certain time daily, the Cron Jobs tab on the App Engine app dashboard says the job was executed successfully but we don't see anything done and what is even weirder we can't find the cron job url request in the logs.

If I request the cron job URL manually it works as expected.

What might be causing this? Is there another way to debug cron jobs?

Comment: does the url in your cron.yaml match the url of your cron job?

Comment: @GwynHowell yes it is

Comment: Could the cron job be hitting a different version or module?  Cron jobs do show up in the logs.

Comment: @GAEfan not sure how this is possible, as the path provided is relative and not absolute.

Comment: Also, the cron hits your appspot.com url, so test that as well.  And search the logs for `'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'AppEngine-Google'`